# Websokets: Should/could I Wireshark my own ports?

Tags: javascript, websocket, wireshark, ddos

I am not a hacker so bear with me. I've seen his module https://www.npmjs.com/package/tshark, I use node.js and websockets.

Could I use wireshark to intercept, sniff and pre-inspect incoming websocket traffic to my own server and boycott/redirect/deny-ip it if it is a ddos?

I would probably have to set up an additional server to do this work, maybe one that is always sniffing incoming traffic to the port..(?)

I would think that on deciding that some message is bad I would have to [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) the message and ether just stop it (like; *with a ray gun* and vaporize/delete it) or add a variable to the message like `'bad':'true'` so the server denies further processing.

**Is this even a feasible idea?**

I could imagine some hacker may wan't to do a number of things

- open up many of the same connections
- open up connections from other domains
- open up connections with headless browsers
- open up connections that do nothing
- open up connections that make the same request infinity
- open up a connection to test sanitation

have I missed any cases?

I am aware that I can check some of these things on my server (like data sanitisation and same origin) but, I am particularly concerned with ddos

EDIT

---

I am very interested in MITM myself. If others can do it to me, why should it be a bad idea do it to ones own self?

Comment: Isn't this what a firewall is for?

Comment: I like firewalls, but I also like onion layers

Comment: I guess the question is why don't you have this "firewall server" on the incoming part? This is what load balancers do anyway.

Comment: What would that be, do you have a link to some info? .....REALLY though I would like to also set up something additional I have control over before something gets to the attack vector! (I wan't extra security layers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I use wireshark to intercept, sniff and pre-inspect incoming websocket traffic to my own server and boycott/redirect/deny-ip it if it is a ddos?

No - Wireshark is a passive sniffer, and does not connect to the networking stack in a fashion that would even *allow* it to "boycott/redirect/deny-ip it".

You would need something that plugs into the stack in such a fashion and, like it or not, I suspect most if not all of those things are called "firewalls", so you might have to learn to prefer firewalls to onion layers.

Comment: Thank you for the good time saving advice Guy. Though I did not suggest that I had an dislike to fire walls in fact what I mean by onion layers are multiple layers of security. This would be security in addition to a firewall.

Comment: No, it would be a firewall in addition to a firewall - something that intercepts traffic before it gets to the networking stack, and discards it if it's deemed to be an attach, *is* a firewall.